# Having Issue in showing dialog box inside ajax success bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a problem in my ajax script it wont show the dialog box after ajax success if i put `datatype: 'json'` and if I remove the `dataType: 'json'` the dialog shows pop after ajax success.

my script only shows my dialogbox if i remove the dataType.

```
$('#OppaForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "Oppa/view/editOther.php",
        data: $('#OppaForm').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
          $("#dialog-confirm-updateOther").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

And I have an ajax script that shows the dialog box even the dataType is pressent.

```
$('#OppaForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
type: "POST",
url: "Oppa/view/photo.php",
dataType: "JSON",
data: $('#OppaForm').serialize(),
cache: false,
success: function (response) {

if (Number(response) == 1)
    {
       $("#dialog-confirm-changedImage").dialog("open");
       $('#imageInput').replaceWith($('#imageInput').val('').clone(true));
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Number(response) == 1)
```

this line will cause problem , beacuse response will not be 1 in case you need data type json 
you can not compare like this

you will need to iterate through your json contents